# Google Colab disk space getting full

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm new to ML and I am now testing some notebooks in Google Colab (using GPU).

My first notebook has been running for a few hours with no complaints about RAM or disk space. Hoever, when running another notebook, I soon get warnings that I am already using around 57 GB of my 68 GB disk space. These warnings only appear in the second notebook, and the disk space icon has only turned yellow in this second one and not in the first one.

I wonder if someone could clarify a bit what happens with this (virtual) disk space? Where are all the heavy files stored and will it reset automatically so that there will be free space again after running these notebooks?

I have tried to find answers on Colab website and forums but so far with no success. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The files were generated by the notebooks that you were running. Most probably, those files are datasets or dependencies downloaded by your notebook. The disk space will be freed after you "factory reset" the runtime.

Comment: @knoop Thank you so much! And yes this is what happened after running them. :)